# Connection between port 3000 frontend and port 4000 backend

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to connect my react frontend with my socketio backend but nothing seem to be actually happening.
Before adding the cors code to my backend I was getting the following errors

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OcnwQOZ' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ocn-i39 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

But when i added cors to my backend my console is clear without any errors.

React frontend

```
import { fabric } from "fabric";
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from "react";

const Canvas = () => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const fabricCanvasRef = useRef(null);
    const socketRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);
        fabricCanvasRef.current = fabricCanvas;
        
        fabricCanvas.isDrawingMode =true;
        fabricCanvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
        fabricCanvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'black';

        socketRef.current = io('http://localhost:4000/');

        fabricCanvas.on('mouse:down', handleMouseDown);
        fabricCanvas.on('mouse:move', handleMouseMove);
        fabricCanvas.on('mouse:up', handleMouseUp);

        return () => {
            fabricCanvas.off('mouse:down', handleMouseDown);
            fabricCanvas.off('mouse:move', handleMouseMove);
            fabricCanvas.off('mouse:up', handleMouseUp);
            socketRef.current.disconnect();
        }
    }, []);

    const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
        const {x, y} = event.pointer;
        socketRef.current.emit('draw:start', {x, y});
    };

    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        if(!fabricCanvasRef.current.isDrawingMode) return;
        const {x, y} = event.pointer;
        socketRef.current.emit('draw:progress', {x, y});
    };

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        socketRef.current.emit('draw:end');
    };

    return (
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={800} height={600}></canvas>
    )
}

export default Canvas;
```

Backend

```
type herconst http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const server = http.createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000/"
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} is connected`);

    socket.on('draw:start', ({x, y}) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('draw:start', {x, y});
    });

    socket.on('draw:progress', ({x, y}) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('draw:progress', {x, y});
    });

    socket.on('draw:end', () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('draw:end')
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`User ${socket.id} disconnected`);
    })
});

const port = 4000;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Websocket server listening to port ${port}`)
});
```

I added cors in the backend but now the console is clear but I dont get the user id of the user connnected in the console which is there in backend script.

Comment: `const io = require('socket.io')(http, {` -> `const io = require('socket.io')(server, {`

Comment: the socket.io and socket.io-client are the same version?

Comment: Another thing, if all versions are fine, then please provide the error of the event by listening to `FRONTENDioCLIENT.on('connect_error', (err) => {
      console.error('connect_error due to ', err);
    });` and post. please

Comment: Yes the version for socket.io and socket.io-client are the same

Comment: Did you ignore my comment?

Answer (score 1):

First check if version of `socket.io` and `socket.io-client` are the same.

If yes, then you need a backend like:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
import {createServer} from 'http';
import {Server} from 'socket.io';


// Allows FRONTEND application to make HTTP requests to Express application
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    app.use(cors());
    next();
});

app.use(cors());
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const ioServer = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['YOURDOMAIN.COM',
            'YOUR-OTHER-DOMAIN.COM',
            'http://localhost:3000'],
        methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    }
});
let port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
ioServer.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
    // your events
});

httpServer.listen(port);

console.info('=======================================================');
console.info('SERVER CREATED');
console.info(`url:  http://localhost:${port}`);
httpServer.on('listening', port);
console.info('=======================================================');
```